# Python Tensorflow 2.3.1 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte, invalid continuation byte. UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python, tensorflow, unicode, pycharm

I'm trying to train an object detection model, but I can't make it work. I'm trying based on this:
htps://gilberttanner.com/blog/tensorflow-object-detection-with-tensorflow-2-creating-a-custom-model
but in pycharm.

My issue is that I got the following error when running model_main_tf2.py:
[utf-8 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqMXN.png)

Python version is the latest 3.8 Pycharm 2020.2.3 and tensorflow 2.3.1. I had to add the object_detection folder to the tensorflow manually because pycharm couldn't manage to get it right.
[Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mPQa.png)

The main problem is here:

[self._read](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTDgP.png)

I tried creating the .record files with latin-1 encoding but no luck

Edit:
Used this to convert the labelled images to .csv files:[xml_to_csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvu9P.png)
This to create the tf files:[tfpic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGBSg.png) [tfpic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRkGZ.png) [tfpic3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ngIP.png)
Main_module I used: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/model_main.py

With 2 changes: import tensorflow as tf instead of the one in this.
And tf.compat.v1.app.run() instead of the one at the end of this. I had to change a lot of tf functions in the files for object detection because it only works when i call the functions as tf.compat.v1. rather than tf

Comment: I think you may need to post a bit more information - like a minimum reproducible case for the error. I get that you've linked to some code from the internet which you have used as a reference, but it's more helpful to contributors to see exactly what you have got.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the similar issue while following [tensorflow object detection guide](https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).

In my case the problem was in the incorrect pipeline.config PATHs (I thought PATHs were already specified for me when i copied them, but I was wrong).

Not sure if it will help you, but it would be nice if it works.